# Hook into Java EE container managed transations

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, jta

I'm having trouble finding my way through some not very popular features of the Java EE. I have been trying to use a mixture of Java EE and non-Java EE patterns in combination but somehow can't really find a proper solution.

Lets say I have following structures and classes in my application:

**JAX-RS resource(s):**
this is a simple resource with some methods that make calls to one or multiple services in their process. this is where a request comes into the system and this is where a transaction should be started per request.

Services are injected into resources using CDI's `@Inject`.

**Service classe(s):**
EJB or CDI managed beans, which contain some business logic and make calls to one or more repositories to do their job.

Again repositories are injected into services.

**Repository(ies):**
EJB or CDI managed beans, responsible for retrieving or storing data from/into database.

They need a JDBC connection which I'm not sure what the proper way for obtaining it is.

**Publishers for external systems**
these are responsible to make some calls to external systems to let them know of changes in the system.

I want to use JTA container managed transaction for both DB operations and also for external publishers. However I have following problems and can't find proper information for it:

- How to start transaction on each call to JAX-RS methods? is a `@Transactional` annotation on class level enough?
- On repositories, I'm not sure how to properly inject DB connection so that the transaction is setup on it properly. I thought about using a `@TransactionScoped` bean to create and provide the connection to all repositories and then call its commit or rollback using `beforeCompletion` callback by examining `TransactionManager.getStatus`
- How to hook publishers into the transaction lifecycle so that calls to external systems are only made if the transaction is successful. Will a similar solution like repositories using a shared `@TransactionScoped` bean work here too?

I can't use JPA as the underlying database is a NoSql one. Also worth to know that the application will be hosted in a Java EE 7 compliant container.

**UPDATE**
adding some sample code:
Where this is the JAX-RS resource:

```
@Path("test")
@Transactional
public class TestResource {

    @Inject
    private SomeService someService;

    @GET
    @Path("get-from-service")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getFromService() {
        return someService.getStatus();
    }

}
```

this is the service:

```
public class SomeService {

    @Inject
    private SomeExternalPublisher someExternalPublisher;

    private static int instanceCount = 0;

    public SomeService() {
        instanceCount++;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return
                "Service instance count: " + instanceCount +
                        "   external publisher status: " + someExternalPublisher.getStatus();
    }

}
```

and this is the publisher:

```
@TransactionScoped
public class SomeExternalPublisher implements SessionSynchronization, Synchronization, Serializable {

    private static String status;
    private static int instances = 0;
    private static int beforeCompletion = 0;
    private static int afterCompletion = 0;
    private static int afterBegin = 0;
    private static int afterCompletionEJB = 0;

    public SomeExternalPublisher() {
        instances++;

        status = "instances: " + instances + " beforeCompletions: " + beforeCompletion + " afterCompletions: " + afterCompletion + " afterBegins: " + afterBegin + " afterCompletionEJBs: " + afterCompletionEJB;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterBegin() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
        afterBegin++;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(boolean committed) throws EJBException, RemoteException {
        afterCompletionEJB++;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeCompletion() {
        beforeCompletion++;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(int status) {
        afterCompletion++;
    }
}
```

non of the callbacks on the publisher are ever called, so the response of the `GET application-path/get-from-service` is always like this:

```
Service instance count: 4   external publisher status: instances: 5 beforeCompletions: 0 afterCompletions: 0 afterBegins: 0 afterCompletionEJBs: 0
```

Comment: could you explain in more details what "transactional resources" you need to be working with?  So far it sounds like 2 resource types: 1) JDBC connections and 2) "publishers for external systems".  Although CDI/JAX-RS/EJB have first-class transaction support (via annotations), the classes themselves are not considered transactional resources.  Rather, they typically manage transactional resources (e.g. JDBC Connections or JPA entities)

Comment: you are right, those classes have to manage transactional resources: JDBC connections and publishers. in case of publishers, I have an array of "events" that should be published to external systems ONLY in case the whole transaction succeeds. However I cant find how a publisher shall be informed about success in TRs.

Comment: It sounds like this answer describes the solution you need (hooking custom resources into JTA transactions using a JCA Resource Adapter) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736241/using-arbitrary-resources-with-jta